# Algorithm run from within Node HTTP request takes much longer to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, algorithm, mongoose

I have a node app which plots data on an x,y dot plot graph. Currently, I make a GET request from the front end and my back end node server accepts the requests, loops through an array of data points, draws a canvas using [Node Canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) and streams it back to the front end where it's displayed as a PNG image.

Complicating things is that there are can be polygons so my algorithm calculates if a point is inside a polygon, using the [point in polygon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/point-in-polygon) package, and colors that data point differently if it is.

This works fine when there are less than 50,000 data points. However, when there are 800,000 the request takes approximately 23 seconds. I have profiled the code and most of that time is spent looping through all the data points and figuring out where to plot it on the canvas and what color (depending on if it's in one or more polygons). Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/asZ13BhdmYOKFRjAhHTZ?p=preview) i made. Basically i do something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  // get raw points
  x = data[i][0];
  y = data[i][1];

  // convert to a point on canvas
  pointX = getPointOnCanvas(x);
  pointY = getPointOnCanvas(y, 'y');

  color = getColorOfCell(pointX, pointY);

  color = color;

  plotColor.push({
      color: color,
      pointX: pointX,
      pointY : pointY
  });

}

// draw the dots down here
```

The algorithm itself is not the problem. The issue I have is that when the algorithm is run within a HTTP request, it takes a long time to calculate what color a point is - about 16 seconds. But if do it in chrome on the front end, it takes just over a second (see the plunker). When I run the algorithm on the command line with Node, it takes less than a second. So the fact that my app runs the algorithm within a HTTP request is slowing it down massively. So couple of questions:

Why would this be? Why does running an algorithm from within a HTTP request take so much longer?

What can I do to fix this, if anything? Would it somehow be possible to make a request to start the task, and then notify frontend when finished and retrieve the PNG?

**EDIT**
I fully tested running the algorithm and creating a PNG through the command line. It's much quicker, less than half a second to work out what color each of the 800k data points should be. Im thinking of using socket to make a request to the server and start the task, then have it return the image. I'm baffled though why the code should take so long when run within a HTTP request...

**EDIT**
The problem is Mongo and Mongoose. I store the coordinates of each polygon in Mongo. I fetch these coordinates once but when I compare them to each x, y point/. Somehow, this is what's massively delaying the algoritm. If I close the Mongo document, the algorithm goes from 16 seconds to 1.5 seconds......

**Edit**
@DevDig pointed out the main problem in the comments section - when using a Mongoose object there are lots of getters and setters slowing it down. Using lean() in the query reduces algorithm from 16 seconds to 1.5 seconds

Comment: Does the Plunker have 800,000 points? It does take about 4 seconds for it to complete, and not 700 milliseconds as stated when done.

Comment: Yes it does have 800k. The time you see is the time it took to calculate what color each point is. The rest of the time is spend plotting on the canvas. Im not worried about that because Node is super quick at that part. But is slow at calculating whether a point is in a polygon ONLY when algorithm is run within a HTTP request...

Comment: I don't really have an answer for you, but I did cut the execution time almost in half pretty much just by replacing `every` and `forEach` with `for`-loops: https://plnkr.co/edit/BfE35V9eTxfUpKIiC58N?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, ill implement that

Comment: Is it a single request? Or when you try to access it via web do you get multiple requests?

Comment: @htkibar Its a single request...

Comment: Still, if you haven’t, you should try setting keepAlive to true in your requests.

Comment: As far as my experience goes, mongoose does not handle big results well. Using lean queries sped things up massively: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean

Comment: @DevDig thanks, that worked

Comment: add a reply @DevDig so you can get the bounty by the owner

Answer (score 2):

Just finished running a version of your code as a nodeJS service. The code is taken from your plunker. Execution time was 171mSec for 100,000 rows in data (replicated first 10K rows 10 times. Here's what I did:

First, your data.json and gates.json files aren't really JSON files, they are javascript files. I removed the var data/gates = statements from the front and removed the ending semicolon. The issue you're encountering may have to do with how you're reading in your data sets in your app. Since you don't modify gates or data, I read them in as part of the set-up on the server, which is exactly how you are processing in the browser. If you need to read the files in each time you access the server, then that, of course, will change the timing. That change took the execution time from 171mSec to 515mSec - still nothing near what you're seeing. This is being executed on a macBook Pro. If needed, I can update timings from a network accessed cloud server.

getting the files:

```
 var fs = require("fs");
 var path = require("path");
 var data = [];
 var allGatesChain;
 var events = [];
 var x, y, pointX, pointY;

 var filename = __dirname + "/data.txt";

 data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, "utf-8"));
 filename = __dirname + "/gates.json";
 var gates = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(filename, "utf-8"));
```

I moved your routines to create allGatesChain and events into the exported function:

```
  allGatesChain = getAllGatesChain();
  generateData();
  console.log("events is "+events.length+" elements long. events[0] is: "+events[0]);
  console.log("data is "+data.length+" elements long. data[0] is "+data[0]);
```

and then ran your code:

```
  var start, end;
  var plotColor = [];
  start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    // get raw points
    x = data[i][0];
    y = data[i][1];
    // convert to a point on canvas
    pointX = getPointOnCanvas(x);
    pointY = getPointOnCanvas(y, 'y');
    color = getColorOfCell({
      gateChain: allGatesChain,
      events: events,
      i: i
    });
    color = color;
    plotColor.push({
        color: color,
        pointX: pointX,
        pointY : pointY
    });
  }
  end = new Date().getTime();
  var _str = "loop execution took: "+(end-start)+" milliseconds.";
  console.log(_str);
  res.send(_str);
```

result was 171mSec.

Comment: thanks, ill go through all this later and update question!